# Unpacking table in a function call

Tags: lua

Without giving too much details, this sample snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
-- Add an extra predefined argument
function one_more_arg(...)                                                                        
    local args = {...}
    return function()
        print(table.unpack(args), "c")
    end
end

local my_new_print = one_more_arg("a", "b")
my_new_print()  -- "a   c"
```

Apparently unpacking a table does not work in this scenario. Any ideas on how to make this work, ie `print` will receive `"a", "b", "c"`? I'm trying to avoid modifying `args`, unless it's the only way to achieve it.

Comment: `local args = {...}; table.insert(args, "c")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you place table.unpack() as an argument to function there should be no other arguments or it should be the last one. Otherwise only first value from table will be passed.

> Lua always adjusts the number of results from a function to the
>   circumstances of the call. When we call a function as a statement, Lua
>   discards all of its results. When we use a call as an expression, Lua
>   keeps only the first result. We get all results only when the call is
>   the last (or the only) expression in a list of expressions. These
>   lists appear in four constructions in Lua: multiple assignment,
>   arguments to function calls, table constructors, and return
>   statements.

From http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html

So you can try to put `unpack` at the end if it is ok for you:

```
print("c", table.unpack(args))
```

Or modify `args`.

Comment: Third option: If possible, use an [external C library](https://github.com/moteus/lua-vararg): `print(vararg.append("c", table.unpack(args)))`.

Answer (score -1):

```
table.concat (list [, sep [, i [, j]]])
```

Given a list where all elements are strings or numbers, returns the string list[i]..sep..list[i+1] ··· sep..list[j]. The default value for sep is the empty string, the default for i is 1, and the default for j is #list. If i is greater than j, returns the empty string.